# How to replace some text with another text dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 clients for a web application(shoppiong portal) in which for one client i need to show products price as **points** where as for another client i need to show **Rs** in place of Point.

Is there any way to handle such condition dynamically in which i can replace some text with another in whole application based on client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a Clients table in your database you can have a column for that, or you can use your Web config, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Resources or Settings mechanism which serves as dictionary application wise. Using it you can replace whatever terminology you need, the only thing taken into consideration is that you need to use appropriate resource/settings file based on client.

For More

[Resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/resource_files_in_asp_net.aspx)